# Getting all X & Y Coordinates while dragging/ moving finger

Tags: android

When I touch once (`MotionEvent.Action_Down`) it gives me accurate and all X & Y Coordinates, but when I touch and move my finger (`MotionEvent.Action_Move`) then it's giving some touched coordinates.

For Example

I am dragging my finger on y axis of 10 to 150 and it's accurate I am moving my finger on this axis but it's giving me

> 10 13 15 19 20 25 26 28 29 31

I'm getting all these by `event.getY()` in my Logcat see the diff. 1st 10 then 13 but i moved my finger on 11,12 also and its not giving coordinates of that all my code is in ontouchevent

Can anybody Help me ??

Comment: Why do you need all the coordinates?

Comment: there are some lines on my app and i want to check if finger touched the Line or not i tried every solution but nothing is working to get to coordinates

Comment: You can linearly interpolate between the coordinates, and see if the interpolated line intersects your lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just something you'll have to live with, perhaps you can generate a best fit line that goes through most of your points and use that?

The touchscreen controller is not infinitely fast and it can't capture every single pixel that your finger slides across, it just has to sample the screen every so often.

Can you say what you need to use this data for?

Comment: actually its a bunch of lines and i want if user touched any line then  exit or Game Over .. its work when we move our finger slow on the app so it get all coordinates and if that coordinate match then exit..

Answer (score 0):

To find out if someones finger intersects your lines, you can test each adjacent pair of touch coordinates and test that against your line.

The following page has some Java code which can be used to test for an intersection of two lines:
http://www.ahristov.com/tutorial/geometry-games/intersection-lines.html

Assuming you use the method from that page, and assuming you have an array of touch points called points, you could test for intersection with code like the following:

```
boolean doesIntersect = intersection(points[i-1].x, points[i-1].y, points[i].x, points[i].y, yourlinestart.x, yourlinestart.y, yourlineend.x, yourlineend.y);
```

Comment: sorry for asking again do you mean points is my touched one which i touched on my app ?? if yes then it will check on games end that user crossed it or not but i can mod it for my game  Wait i will make the code and check if its work or not then i will mark it as answer :)

Comment: Yes, the points array will be all the points you know.your user has touched. You don't actually need an array, you just need the current point and the last point.

Comment: Ian i don't think line intersection will help me because i am not getting the Coordinates while moving my fingers so without getting that x and y point how could i check it intersect or not it will always return null or false

Comment: For this to work you need to store the coordinates of the current and last touch points. I don't think there's anyway around that.